# include jquery plugin file not working

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

My code for include js as follows:

```
function you_fancy_js(){
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min', 'jquery.validate.min' ) );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','you_fancy_js');
add_action('admin_head','you_fancy_js');
```

The above code should include a js file. It is not working.

Comment: @Joseph Leaving notes to OP _inside_ the edit, is not kool. It doesn't improve the question - please use comments for that.

Comment: @Himanshu Do not spread information about your problem in comments. Update your question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your uses of `wp_register_script` and `add_action` are incorrect. Try the following code:

```
function you_fancy_js(){
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-validate' ) );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','you_fancy_js');
```

This assumes that your custom jQuery functions are in `jquery.js` and `jquery`, `jquery-ui-core`, and `jquery-validate` are already enqueued. You do not need `admin_head`. The admin equivalent of `wp_enqueue_scripts` is [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/svipl_portfolio/js/jquery.js"></script>                                                       <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/svipl_portfolio/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
                                                     <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/svipl_portfolio/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you are in the admin panel, jQuery and possibly jQuery UI should already be loaded. If not, add `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` and `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core')` followed by your validation script before your custom script(s). There is no need to bring your own versions of jQuery and jQuery-UI as they are already included with WordPress.